# NVDA Screen reader issue

Tags: screen

I am using NVDA Screen reader. It happens to just read the title of my window and nothing else. Say All is on. It just says "unknown" for everything else. Does someone else have the same issue? Is there some setting that has to be changed? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I have the same issue, but I have no idea if it's a bug or how it can be changed :-( Looking for a solution here, too.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer...

this happens only when I run the program (debug) from within Visual Studio. When I start the .exe itself its working properly.